# Pressure at equal heights inside of a U-tube containing two different immiscible liquids

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Consider the following picture:

[image]

It is given that the liquid in the right tube is denser than the liquid on the left tube.
Call these two liquids $A$ and $B$, so $\rho_A < \rho_B$.
At both points $C$, the pressures are equal, since pressure is given by
$$p = p_0 + \rho gh,$$
and $p_0 = p_C$, $g=g$, and $h=h$ for both sides of the tube.
However, we are given that $\rho_A < \rho_B$, therefore, it naturally follows that $$p_0 + \rho_A gh < p_0 + \rho_B gh,$$
but this is not what the textbook claims; it claims that the pressure at $A$ is greater than the pressure at $B$, however, this seems like a contradiction to the above derivation. Why?

Comment: It looks like there's some confusion about what $h$ means. This parameter is the depth below a reference interface; in this case, the free surface where $p=p_0$. This certainly isn't the same for both sides of the tube.